# How can i divide like triangle?

Tags: mesh

How can I divide an icosphere like that?

The tutorial told to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, but it is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The tool you are looking for is called 'Poke Faces'.

If can also be activated from the *Mesh* menu in edit mode under the *Faces* submenu (i.e.  Mesh ‣ Faces ‣ Poke Faces).

see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#poke-faces for more info.

In Blender 2.8, the *Faces* sub menu has been moved out to be its own full menu. It also appears that the alt-p shortcut is not defined, so that is likely to be your problem.
See:
[image]

Comment: thank you. poke faces works. but this is not there mesh - face

Comment: @shuung if you are using blender 2.8, see my edit.

Comment: aw my english is bad i can't understand but thank you. i solve it to search it

Comment: @shuung added a picture

Comment: ah! thank you so much!